# Replacing img src with different src gives 404 in the console

Tags: javascript

In a script I'm using (jQuery but that's not relevant to the question) I have:

```js
$(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('.png','.gif'));
```

This works fine, but I noticed that after I've replaced the PNG, the console shows:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
>       https://www.example.com/image.png

I like my current setup, but given the errors (multiple as I do the replacement on multiple images) this is probably a bad idea. Should I instead replace the whole `<img>` tag?

Comment: Are you sure the second source has the image and it itself is not giving 404 when opened in new tab?

Comment: Why would replacing the <img> be any different? The browser does those requests before you replace them.

Comment: I would guess the error message comes from the `img` before you replace the file extension.

Comment: Please add some explanation so other can understand !
And if possible add your tried code so we can help you.